# KEDAScalerFailed rpc error: code = PermissionDenied desc = Permission monitoring.timeSeries.list denied (or the resource may not exist)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, publish-subscribe, autoscaling, keda

I'm testing Keda's autoscaling with pubsub. the scaler works well when I use service account json credentials. When I switch to gcp workload identity using PodIdentity: gcp it throws error message:
rpc error: code = PermissionDenied desc = Permission monitoring.timeSeries.list denied (or the resource may not exist)
I have already added roles/monitoring.metricWriter to the service account. not sure how to fix the problem. Thanks!

roles/monitoring.metricWriter added